# When I try to get a background on my website with css/html it wont show the background

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to get a background on my website BJBGaming1.com, and i have this

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>BJBGaming1</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://dhbhdrzi4tiry.cloudfront.net/cdn/sites/foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body>
```

and if you look i have the css/main.css part which has this for code

```
html {
min-height:100%;
min-width:100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
width: 100%;
} 
body {  
background-image:url('../img/background.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```

and i have an image that matches the name background.png that is 1 folder back and into the img folder so i have the ../img/background.png but the background still wont show, somebody please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `!important` to the `background-image` because foundation.css is already override your background image to `#fefefe`

```
html {
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
} 
body {  
    background-image:url('../img/background.png') !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

**OR**

You can also load your main.css file after foundation.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dhbhdrzi4tiry.cloudfront.net/cdn/sites/foundation.min.css">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Thank you, i did everything you said but it wont cover the whole website. you can see what i mean at BJBGaming1.com

Comment: i just made it so that it uses pixel size but do you know to make it so it fits exactly perfect and so it covers the background

Comment: Try adding `background-attachment: fixed;` to the body css and change `background-size` to `100% auto` it should make your background fixed and fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome developer tools, I can get your image to display using

```
body { background-image: url('../img/background.png') !important; }
```

and

body { background-size: 100% !important;} will work

or body { background-size: cover !important; } worked as well.